# I want to make a Class without using numpy but there's something wrong

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, class, oop

I'm trying to get used to how to use Class but I think I made some mistakes.
The first error that occurs to me is this:
TypeError: **init**() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'N' and 'M'
If I cannot make a matrix with random integers, then I cannot make others... 
so I'm very crazy about fixing this problem... :( please help me!

```
import random
```

from typing import List

class Numpy:
def **init**(self, N: int, M: int):
### Edit Here ###
self.N = N
self.M = M
# make matrix with randInt
self.matrix = [[]]
self.randInt()
#################

```
def __str__(self):
    ### Edit Here ###
    return str(self.matrix)
    # print matrix
    #################

def randInt(self) -> List[List[int]]:
    ### Edit Here ###
    # make random int N * M matrix
    self.matrix = [[random.randint(0, 100) for row in range(self.N)] for column in range(self.M)]
    #################


def mean(self, axis: int) -> List[int]:
    ### Edit Here ###
    self.axis = axis
    if self.axis == 1:
        mean = []
        for j in range(self.M):
            s = 0
            for i in range(self.N):
                s += self.matrix[j][i]
            mean.append(s/self.M)
    elif self.axis == 0:
        mean = []
        for j in range(self.N):
            s = 0
            for i in range(self.M):
                s += self.matrix[i][j]
            mean.append(s/self.N)
    # calculate mean for each axis
    #################
    return mean

def argmax(self, axis: int) -> List[int]:
    ### Edit Here ###
    # find index of max value for each axis
    if axis == 1:
        index = []
        for i in range(len(self.matrix)):
            index.append(self.matrix[i].index(max(self.matrix[i])))
    elif axis == 0:
        matrix = [[row[i] for row in self.matrix] for i in range(len(self.matrix[0]))]
        index = []
        for i in range(len(matrix)):
            index.append(matrix[i].index(max(matrix[i])))

    #################
    return index

def concatenate(self, mat: List[List[int]], axis: int):
    ### Edit Here ###
    # concatenate mat to existing matrix
    if axis == 0 :
        return self.matrix + mat
    elif axis == 1:
        for i in range(self.M):
            self.matrix[i] = self.matrix[i] + mat[i]
        return self.matrix
    #################

def zeros(self, N: int, M: int) -> List[List[int]]:
    ### Edit Here ###
    # make N * M matrix with all zero values
    self.N = N
    self.M = M
    zeros = [([0]*self.N) for i in range(self.M)]
    #################
    return zeros
```

Comment: You are missing the `__init__` parameters in `self.matrix = Numpy().randInt(self.N, self.M)`, but the bigger issue is the creation of a class instance in `__init__`. You will get `RecursionError`. Replace `Numpy()` with `self`.

Comment: I also find it strange to call the class Numpy. Why do you call your class with this name that is already often used for an other reason in python?

Comment: @Guy thank you!! I changed Numpy() to self but I don't understand the missing parameter part of __init__. Could you explain it more please?
class Numpy:
    def __init__(self, N: int, M: int):
        ### Edit Here ###
        self.N = N
        self.M = M
        # make matrix with randInt
        self.matrix = self.randInt(self.N, self.M)
..

Comment: @Floh I'm practicing understand the algorithm of numpy functions so I'm making my own Numpy class!

Comment: If `__init__` has parameters you need to fill them (or use the as default parameters) when instantizing the class. You should go over some [tutorials](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html)

Comment: There is also no point in calling `randInt` twice, `print(Numpy(3,2).matrix) should work just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do:

```py
import random
from typing import List

class Matrix:
    def __init__(self, N: int, M: int):
        ### Edit Here ###
        self.N = N
        self.M = M
        # make matrix with randInt
        self.matrix = [[]]
        self.rand_int()
        #################

    def __str__(self):
        ### Edit Here ###
       return str(self.matrix)
        # print matrix
        #################

    def rand_int(self) -> List[List[int]]:
        ### Edit Here ###

        # make random int N * M matrix
        self.matrix = [[random.randint(0, 100) for row in range(self.N)] for column in range(self.M)]
        #################


    def mean(self, axis: int) -> List[int]:
        ### Edit Here ###
        if self.axis == 0:
            mean = []
            for j in range(self.M):
                s = 0
                for i in range(self.N):
                    s += self.matrix[0][i]
                mean.append(s/self.M)
        elif self.axis == 1:
            mean = []
            for j in range(self.N):
                s = 0
                for i in range(self.M):
                    s += self.matrix[0][i]
                mean.append(s/self.N)
        # calculate mean for each axis
        #################
        return mean

    def argmax(self, axis: int) -> List[int]:
        ### Edit Here ###
        # find index of max value for each axis
        x = self.axis
        index = max(range(len(x)), key=lambda i: x[i])
        #################
        return index

    def concatenate(self, mat: List[List[int]], axis: int):
        ### Edit Here ###
        # concatenate mat to existing matrix
        if axis == 0 :
            return self.matrix + mat
        elif axis == 1:
            for i in range(self.M):
                self.matrix[i] = self.matrix[i] + mat[i]
            return self.matrix
        #################

    def zeros(self, N: int, M: int) -> List[List[int]]:
        ### Edit Here ###
        # make N * M matrix with all zero values
        zeros = [([0]*self.M) for i in range(self.N)]
        #################

        return zeros

print(Matrix(3,2))
```

Note that there are few non pythonic ways in this code. For zeros and randint, for example, I would better do factories, which would result in:

```py
import random

class Matrix:
    def __init__(self, matrix=None):
        self.matrix = matrix
    @property
    def n(self):
        return len(self.matrix)

    @property
    def m(self):
        if len(self.matrix) > 0:
            return len(self.matrix[0])
        else:
            return 0


    def __str__(self):
       return str(self.matrix)

    @classmethod
    def rand_int(cls, the_n, the_m):
        my_matrix = cls()
        my_matrix.matrix = [[random.randint(0, 100) for row in range(the_n)] for column in range(the_m)]
        return my_matrix

    @classmethod
    def zeros(cls, the_n, the_m):
        my_matrix = cls()
        my_matrix.matrix = [([0]*the_m) for i in range(the_n)]
        return my_matrix

print(Matrix())
print(Matrix.zeros(3,2))
print(Matrix.rand_int(3,2))
print(Matrix.rand_int(3,2).n)
print(Matrix.rand_int(3,2).m)
```

which results in

```
None
[[0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0]]
[[31, 32, 62], [99, 89, 85]]
2
3
```

Comment: I really appreciate you left feedback on the code. Based on your advice, I edited the code and could finally find some errors in other functions too. I wish I could become so natural to use python like you :)

Comment: And I would like to know why Numpy module doesn't have comma between the lists and the elements. I searched for it and they say it's because it is just the way they display to increase the readablity. Is there any simple method to make the result Just like Numpy? I know I can delete comma between the elements with split function but the comma between the lists, I don't know how to.
for example: change [[1,1],[0,0]] to
[[1 1]
[0 0]]
like this!

Comment: Thank you a lot for the feedback. For your question, you can do this by the `__repr__` function and creating the string yourself by parsing the matrix with for loops and so on, instead of using the `__str__` built-in method of lists (which is called when you do `str(self.matrix)`.

Answer (score 0):

The `__init__` method is called when you create an instance of your `Numpy` class.

So if your `__init__` methods takes 2 arguments `N` and `M`, your last line should be `print(Numpy(2,3))`.

This also means that you are calling the `randInt` method twice:

- once when you create your object, in the `init` method (`Numpy()` should be replaced by `self` though, else you will be calling the method on a new `Numpy` object, and you will have an infinite recursion).
- then when you call the method on your object in the `print` statement.

Moreover, your `randInt` method requires 2 arguments `N` and `M`, but you are not using them since you use the class variables `self.N` and `self.M` in your method.

So to fix your issue, I would suggest you to

1. replace your `print(Numpy().randInt(3,2))` statement with `print(Numpy(3,2))`
2. replace the line `self.matrix = Numpy().randInt(self.N, self.M)` with `self.matrix = self.randInt()`
3. modify your `randInt` function to remove the 2 arguments you do not use : `def randInt(self) -> List[List[int]]:`

Comment: oops, it's embarrassing that I didn't know basic things of Class :( Thanks to your comment it became much clearer to me!! And I'm sorry that I can't vote for your answer since I don't have enough reputation :(